# AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my rails app deployed with AWS Elastic beanstalk. However, when I open my app through Beanstalk environment, everything works fine except the images are not being shown. I tried many things to make it show but still not able to.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I open my app through Beanstalk environment, everything works fine except the images are not being shown"? Also, have you checked the urls of the images being requested? Are they valid?

Comment: I mean, my app is deployed and when I open it through something.elasticbeanstalk.com it opens. The images URL are <img src = "/assets/abc.jpg" /> and it works perfectly on localhost as well as heroku. Having issue with AWS EB.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Rails. If that's the case, you are missing the `asset_path` function.

Instead of:

`<img src = "/assets/abc.jpg" />`

You have to use something like:

`<img src = "<%= asset_path('abc.jpg') %>" />`

more info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I did is copied all my images from /assets/images folder and pasted to public/assets folder and deployed the new version. It works fine. :)

Comment: Note that what you did is a workaround, not the standard for Rails